# Char to int conversion?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to grab the rgb values from 3 editboxes so that I can change the color of a window during run time. The following code is not giving me the numeric values that I need.

```
        const int bufferSize = 1024;
        char fade1Buffer[bufferSize] = "";
        char fade2Buffer[bufferSize] = "";
        char fade3Buffer[bufferSize] = "";

        HWND Editbox1 = GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_MAINFADE1_EDIT); 
        SendMessage(Editbox1, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)fade1Buffer);
        HWND Editbox2 = GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_MAINFADE2_EDIT);
        SendMessage(Editbox2, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)fade2Buffer); 
        HWND Editbox3 = GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_MAINFADE3_EDIT);
        SendMessage(Editbox3, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)bufferSize, (LPARAM)fade3Buffer);

        //fill our main window background
        FadeVert(hWnd, RGB(fade1Buffer, fade2Buffer,fade3Buffer), RGB(255, 255, 255), (int) Client_Rect.top, 
            (int) Client_Rect.left, (int) Client_Rect.right, (int) Client_Rect.bottom);
```

Comment: Is what way are they not giving the correct values?

Comment: This isn't a `char` to `int` conversion. Those are arrays you're passing into the `RGB` macro.

Comment: @ Ed, they return different values than the values in the edit boxes.

Comment: @chris, ok an array.  Any idea how to change the numeric value in the edit box to a numeric value that works with the rgb macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) function converts char* into int. It is under `<cstdlib>`

```
int atoi ( const char * str );
```

**In this case,**

```
int i = atoi(fade1Buffer);
```

See also, [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) as @Keith Thompson and @Chris mentioned. It is a little harder to use, but it handles errors better.

```
   char * pEnd;
   long int i = strtol(fade1Buffer,&pEnd, 10);//10 is the base (decimal in this case)
   //pEnd == fade1Buffer if there is an error.
```

**If you convert it to a C++ style std:: string, you can use several other functions as well**

```
#include <string>
std::string str(fade1Buffer);
int i = stoi(test);
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: `atoi()` does not detect errors. If you want error detection, use `strtol()`.

Comment: `stoi`, `stringstream`, `strtol`. So many better alternatives to choose from.

Comment: Those deal with std::string. The OP is dealing with c-style strings. But yeah, I will add them to the answer. Thanks

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon, Good point. `strtol` would be the obvious choice then.

Comment: @dark, I added #include <string> and I get error C3861: 'stoi': identifier not found.  I have tried atoi and strtol but they seem to only return a value of 0, or perhaps I should say a NULL value,when the value in the editbox is 170.

Comment: Did you try strtol? It will help you by also telling you which part of the string it couldnt parse.

Comment: @dark, with strtol debugger breakpoint tells me pEnd is a <bad ptr> expression cannot be evaluated

Comment: @eric: Is that after the all to `strtol`? You don't initialize it so this would be expected before the call.

Answer (score 3):

There is a function called GetDlgItemInt in Win32. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

This would have reduced the lines of code by 1/3 and all the hassles of converting a string into a number. Moreover you should be careful with LPARAM of WM_GETTEXT. If you have UNICODE defined, then the parameter is expected to be wchar_t* whereas ANSI version expects char*.